# Ruby, how to reference Root namespace?

Tags: ruby, program-entry-point

When I have a module like this:

```
module MyModule
  class MyClass
  end
end
```

I can access/modify `MyModule` referencing it:

```
MyModule.const_set("MY_CONSTANT", "value")
```

But what about the `Root` namespace, the `::` one?, I'm looking for something like:

```
::.const_set("MY_CONSTANT", "value")
```

*The `const_set` thing is just an example, please don't try to solve this concrete situation but the way of actually making reference to the `Root` namespace*

Comment: *Root* module means? Need a bit more clarity..

Comment: may be you mean `main` object, not a root? or `Object` object? If `Object` do as follows: `Object.const_set("MY_CONSTANT", "value")`, then you can use at the main: `::MY_CONSTANT`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What is the root object? If you mean `main` object, you can't set constant at this level:

```
TOPLEVEL_BINDING.eval('self').const_set("MY_CONSTANT", "value")
# NoMethodError: undefined method `const_set' for main:Object
#   from (irb):71
#   from /home/malo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

If you mean `Object` object, do as follows:

```
Object.const_set("MY_CONSTANT", "value")
# => "value"
```

then you can use at the `main`, or at any other level:

```
::MY_CONSTANT
# => "value"
```

#### Adding another confirmation

We can set a constant using `Kernel` or using `Object` and in both cases the constant will be accessible from the *root namespace*:

```
Kernel.const_set("KERNEL_CONSTANT", "value")
Object.const_set("OBJECT_CONSTANT", "value")

puts !!(defined? ::KERNEL_CONSTANT) # => true
puts !!(defined? ::OBJECT_CONSTANT) # => true
```

But if we set a constant in the *root namespace* this constant is actually set in `Object` and not in `Kernel`:

```
::ROOT_CONSTANT = "value"

puts !!(defined? Object::ROOT_CONSTANT) # => true
puts !!(defined? Kernel::ROOT_CONSTANT) # => false
```

Comment: in irb, Kernel.class # => Module, it means that it is a special module, and Module.class # => Object. That's why when you define ::ROOT_CONSTANT = "value", in Kernel namespace you cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a thing like a Root module, however you can get some quite similar thing operating on Object class:

```
def bar
  'bar'
end

class A
  def bar
    'not bar'
  end
  def test
    bar
  end
  def test2
    Object.bar
  end
end

A.new.test  #=> 'not bar'
A.new.test2 #=> 'bar'
```

You can read about the `main` object here: http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/what-is-the-ruby-top-level/

Answer (score -1):

There is no such thing as a root module in Ruby.

You can define a module in the top-level namespace like this:

```
::MY_CONSTANT = "value"
```

If for some reason you *have* to use `const_set` you can do:

```
module Hi
  Kernel.const_set("X", "3")
end

puts X # => 3
```

*`Kernel` is mixed-in into the top-level namespace* so you're effectively defining a constant in the global namespace this way.

Comment: `Kernel` isn't `::`, it is `Object`

Comment: @majioa Your sentence does not make sense. `Kernel` is a module, `Object` is a class that includes `Kernel` and `::` is an operator.

Comment: I've incorrecty said, I meant that the proper application of the `::` is to apply to `Object`, not to `Kernel`.

Comment: @majioa I don't get your point. `::` is the namespace resolution operator. There's not a *proper* or an *improper* application for it?

Comment: The root namespace is `Object`, not `Kernel` as you claim. `::FOO` will look up `FOO` in `Object`, not `Kernel`.

Comment: I'm accepting the @majioa answer because I think it is more accurate, check the "Adding another confirmation" update.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I *never* claimed that `Kernel` is the *root namespace*. Moreover your statement is false. `Object` *is not the root namespace*, it's a common superclass of every object.

Comment: @Agis some my experiences said that evaluation methods to so called 'root' can be appied to Object, and they are automatically mirrored to `Kernel`, and can be accessible from `main`, but not vice-versa.